# Azure DevOps does not serve Angular 10 + RESTful API using Node.js, Express as zipped files and it causes very slow loading

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-devops, angular10

I have Angular 10 app with Node.js, Express, hosted on Azure DevOps. It has a lot of modules from Angular Material library which creates vendor.js bundle with size about 28 MB.

I am a beginner with Azure hosting.

The issue is, when deployed, the app loads very slow - about 3-4 seconds, and the size of the main.js bundle, is 18MB.

I saw that the frontend files were not send as zipped files when deployed to Azure.

So I installed `gzipper` npm package and now I have the original files and their zipped versions in the dist folder.

I also set this command in my package.json in order to optimize the build process:

```
ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer && gzipper compress ./dist
```

But still, **when compiled on localhost, the size of the main.js bundle is about 335KB**, and **when deployed on Azure, its size is around 18MB**.

I can see that the zipped (.gz) files are send to Azure, but I think Azure does not serve them, but instead, it serves the original files with the original size.

The vendor.js file is not minimized, not uglified, I guess I could do it but then Azure will serve its minimized version, not its zipped version again.

What I should do in order to enable Azure to serve the zipped versions of front end files?
I am not very familiar with Azure settings at all.

Is there some easy setup that I could turn on so I can force **Azure to serve the zipped files, instead of original**?

Shouldn't be this set by default?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you spin up your node server locally and request your app with the gzip header does it serve them as zipped files?

Comment: The backend doesnot serve the front end files in my app. They work on different ports.